# Mattermost to https

Tags: docker, mattermost

I downloaded the mattermost using docker

> docker pull mattermost/mattermost-preview:6.4.0

I tried to configure mattermost to listen to https and I have attached the configuration I did. the domain.crt and domain.key are the certificate and key I generated using openssl and already import the certificate manager (I'm using Windows)

[image]

I restarted the docker and browse to https://localhost:8066/, but got ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. can anyone please help?